# How do I change text color when mat-menu-item is disabled

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to set the text color of a mat-menu-item when disabled. How can I do this without hard coding? Below is what I've tried so far.

```
<button mat-menu-item [disabled]="true">
     <span style="color: #ce066b !important;">"Menu Item 1"</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Its about css, have you tried adding in css file .mat-menu-item[disabled] {
  Your css changes
}

Comment: @olscode is correct, just make sure to move your current (non-disabled) style to css as well, otherwise it will override anything in css. this is probably the simplest solution, but perhaps the proper way would be to use themes.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER
In order to do this in CSS you must remove the hard coded styling from your span and add a class to either button or span like so:

```
<button class="mat-menu-item" mat-menu-item [disabled]="true">
     <span>"Menu Item 1"</span>
</button>
```

Here is a link to the updated stackblitz which shows this working.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yjdoe9

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER
The comments are correct in that this is a CSS issue but not quite correct in the proposed solution.

In particular note the transpiled HTML below. If you view the source of your HTML you will notice it does not add any classes but simply allows strings to be passed to the [disabled] attribute.

```
<button _ngcontent-ubj-c45="" disabled="">
  <span _ngcontent-ubj-c45="" style="color: #ce066b !important;">"Menu Item 1"</span>
</button>
```

(NOTE: if you remove the mat-menu-item attribute, your disabled attribute won't work since you are passing a string with a value of "true" rather than a boolean with a value of true)

Here is a stack blitz which illustrates the correct approach.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9z9erk

```
<button class="mat-menu-item" [disabled]="true">
  <span style="color: #ce066b !important;">"Menu Item 1"</span>
</button>
```

And as stated in the commments here is the CSS

```
.mat-menu-item[disabled] { 
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: If you replace `background-color` with `color` and `orange` with `blue`, it doesn't work which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have edited your question and updated my answer